# Is there a way to customize the placement of concatenated charts in Altair?

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I have the following chart in Altair, and I was wondering if there is a way to change the orientation of the map chart. I have tried using the "center" and "spacing" parameters, but to no avail. I want the map to appear under the legend to make the overall chart more concise.

[image]

This is the code used to generate the charts:

```
background = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(
        fill='white',
        stroke='lightgray'
    ).properties(
        width=200,
        height=200
    ).project('albersUsa')

# Generate the points themselves
climate_points = alt.Chart(climate_with_temps).mark_circle(size=300).encode(
    alt.Longitude('lon:Q'),
    alt.Latitude('lat:Q'),
    alt.OpacityValue(0.25),
    alt.Color('city:N', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='dark2'), legend=None)
).properties(
    title=alt.TitleParams(
        ['Location of Coastal Cities'],
        baseline='bottom',
        orient='bottom',
        fontSize=15   
    )
)

map_chart = background + climate_points

temp_line_plot = alt.Chart(climate_with_temps).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X('month:O', axis=alt.Axis(title="Month"), sort=list(set(climate_with_temps.city))),
    alt.Y('avg_temp:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title="Average Temperature in Fahrenheit"), scale=alt.Scale(domain=[30, 95])),
    alt.Color('city:N'),
    alt.OpacityValue(1)
).properties(
    height=500,
    width=700
)

sun_square_plot = alt.Chart(climate_with_temps).mark_square().encode(
    alt.X('month:O', axis=alt.Axis(title="Month"), sort=list(set(climate_with_temps.city))),
    alt.Y('avg_temp:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title="Average Temperature in Fahrenheit"), scale=alt.Scale(domain=[30, 95])),
    alt.Color('city:N', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='dark2'), legend=alt.Legend(title='City')),
    alt.Size('sun_bin:O', sort=['0 - 50', '50 - 99', '100 - 149', '150 - 199', '200 - 249', '250 - 299', '300 - 350'], legend=alt.Legend(title='Average Hours of Sunshine')),
    alt.OpacityValue(1)
).properties(
    height=500,
    width=700
)

left_chart = sun_square_plot + temp_line_plot
final = alt.hconcat(left_chart, map_chart, center=False, spacing=0)
```

Comment: I see that you are using a solution for the legend in your newly asks question. Please accept and upvote my answer below if that helped you solve the issue you were having here, or post your own answer if you found another issue. Please also include sample data in your question and you will be able to get more detailed help, see [mre] for more info.

Comment: Will do--thank you! Accepted the other one as well. Apologies, I'm a bit new to asking questions on Stack Overflow and still learning the interface.

Comment: Thank you and no worries! Your questions are great and I just wanted to give some additional tips/info in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a straightforward to achieve this, although you could do something like this:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

chart1 = alt.Chart(source, height=400).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
    size='Cylinders'
)
chart2 = alt.Chart(source, height=200, width=200).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
)

# Empty chart for spacing
chart3 = alt.Chart(height=180, width=180).mark_circle(opacity=0)

(chart1 | (chart3 & chart2)).configure_legend(
    orient='right',
    direction='vertical',
    offset=-220,
    symbolDirection='vertical'
)
```

[image]

But the simplest might be to create a horizontal legend above both charts instead:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

chart1 = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
    size='Cylinders'
)

chart2 = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin'
)

(chart1 | chart2).configure_legend(
    orient='top'
)
```

[image]